# Symfony 3 - How to set currently logged user as entity "author"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Let's assume, that I have two entity classes:
`\AppBundle\Entity\User` - user provider;
`\AppBundle\Entity\Article` - simple article.

The `Article` class also have these properties:
`author` - indicating on user which created this particular entity;
`updatedBy` - indicating on user which lately updated content of particular article.

How to pass currently logged user object to `Article` entity to set specific values on `author` and/or `updatedBy` properties on backend generated by [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) on *Symfony 3.0.1*?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with `symfony2`, when it is explicitly about `symfony3`?

Comment: @cezar Still very small amount of people is using `symfony3` tag and Symfony 3 is not really so much different from Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a Controller you just do that

```
$article->setAuthor($this->getUser());
$article->setUpdatedBy($this->getUser());
```

**Or**

If you want that this is automatic

You need to declare a listener on Doctrine event. In your case I guess on preUpdate by including the current user.

There is a very nice documentation here  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

**I edit here to answer at your comment**

Don't worry you can inject the user entity when you declare your listener as Service

For example :

```
services:
    your_listener:
        class:     App\AppBundle\Your_Listener
        arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

Your listener :

```
private $current_user;

public function __construct($security_context) {
        if ($security_context->getToken() != null) {
            $this->current_user = $security_context->getToken()->getUser();
        }
    }
```

Now you can do

```
$entity= $args->getEntity(); // get your Article

if (!$entity instanceof Article) {
        return;
}

$entity->setAuthor($this->current_user);
$entity->setUpdatedBy($this->current_user);
```

Comment: I would like to take 2nd approach. How to include current user object instance to my listener class?

Comment: Look at the documentation 

You need this as parameter : LifecycleEventArgs $args to get the user entity like this : $entity = $args->getEntity();

Just here in the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-listener-class

Hope this is can help you

Comment: Yeah, but when I'm updating `Article` entity, I will get this class instance in `$args->getEntity();` and not a User. I want to set current logged user as author of this particular entity.

Comment: I changed my answer to answer you

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot! But two things about Your answer: 1. Add proper tag to service :). 2. Token check should be in other listener method (not in constructor). For example `preUpdate()`. In constructor, I think, there should be just assigning content to a private value, because the token in constructor is `null` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590621/tokenstorage-sometimes-returns-null-in-service).

Comment: I had never heard about tag so thanks too, I will see that ! Yes it's maybe better to have a service which load the user and use tag when you need it

Comment: As documentation says, service should have "tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }"

Comment: Did you use the Symfony security system when you log ? If no this is normal that you get a null user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108791/discussion-between-francois-dupont-and-krzysztof-trzos).

Answer (score 0):

If you have relations to Author entity

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = new User();
$user->setAuthor($this->getUser());
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

on controller but that is bad idea. Use Command or another design pattern.

Comment: The entity `Article` has the method `setAuthor`, not the entity `User`. You have mixed some things.

Comment: Sorry but that example how you can save current User as article author.